# Disable button until bluetooth connected

Tags: android-bluetooth

I have an android app that automatically turns on device Bluetooth and connects to a paired device. The device sends data which is updated constantly. If the user presses an enable device button, which is used to initialize the device and begin the operation, before the connection is established, all the previous data is reset.

This is an Android project I was given from an outsourced company so I didn't write the code originally. I have

```
private void initialize() {
        // initializing and launching the Equipment layer api
        try {
            Utility.writeLogs(this, getString(R.string.info), TAG, 
"Initializing EState Manager");
           EStateManager.getInstance().launch(getResources());
           getInfo();
           requestConfiguration();
           findViewById(R.id.btn_enable).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           handleConnectionDialog();
       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utility.writeLogs(this, getString(R.string.error), TAG, 
"EStateManger initialization failed");
            Utility.writeLogs(this, getString(R.string.error), TAG, e);
       }
    }


private void handleConnectionDialog() {

    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            // do stuff
            if (!EStateManager.getInstance().isDataReceived()) {
                if (!new PrefUtil(this).isConnectionDialogEnabled()) {
                    runOnUiThread(() -> 
onShowPopup(Utility.POPUP_MAP.get(14)));
                }
            } else {
                if (!buttonPressed) {

findViewById(R.id.btn_enable).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                EStateManager.getInstance().setDataReceived(false);
            }
        }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

I would like to disable the button until Bluetooth is successfully connected to ensure that saved parameters are not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a broadcast receiver to listen for [ACTION_STATE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED)

Then check the extra `EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE` and enable the button if it is `STATE_CONNECTED`

Also in the `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` receiver, check for `STATE_DISCONNECTED`, and disabled the button.

Response to comment:

findViewById should be allowed in the receiver if it is defined in the MainActivity.java like so

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

...

    private final BroadcastReceiver mRadioReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                String action = intent.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case ACTION__DEVICE_CONNECTED:
                        button.setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    case ACTION_DEVICE_DISCONNECTED:
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Eric, thank you for helping me get this far.

I have added a broadcast receiver and made everything work. I don't understand how to start an activity in the receiver though. My button that I would like to disable is laid out in xml so it is identified by findViewById(R.id.btnName).setEnabled which, I'm guessing you know and I did not know, is not allowed in the receiver. How would I best accomplish that?

Comment: I updated my answer. You should be able to use `findViewById(R.id.btnName).setEnabled` in your receiver if your receiver is defined in your Activity.

Comment: That fixed that problem but I still can't get it to work. ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED was a suggestion when I tried it. Does ACTION_DEVICE_CONNECTED require an import?